# ¿Cómo obtener ubicación geográfica por dirección IP en ASP.NET MVC?

Tags: c#, asp.net-mvc, asp.net-core

Quiero obtener la información de la ubicación geográfica por dirección IP, me estoy basando en un proyecto de Asp.Net Core pero me marca error en la linea [image: fgfd]

Código del Controlador :

```
 public class HomeController : Controller
{
    public async Task<IActionResult> Index(string ip)
    {
        if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
        {
            ip = Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();

        }
        Datos model = await Datos.QueryGeographicalLocationAsync(ip);

        return View(model);
    }


}
```

Modelo:

```
public class Datos
{
    [JsonProperty("ip")]
    public string IP { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country_code")]

    public string CountryCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("country_name")]

    public string CountryName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("region_code")]

    public string RegionCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("region_name")]

    public string RegionName { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("city")]

    public string City { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("zip_code")]

    public string ZipCode { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("time_zone")]

    public string TimeZone { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("latitude")]

    public float Latitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("longitude")]

    public float Longitude { get; set; }

    [JsonProperty("metro_code")]

    public int MetroCode { get; set; }

    private Datos() { }

    public static async Task<Datos> QueryGeographicalLocationAsync(string ipAddress)
    {
        HttpClient client = new HttpClient();
        string result = await client.GetStringAsync("http://freegeoip.net/json/" + ipAddress);

        return JsonConvert.DeserializeObject<Datos>(result);
    }
}
```

Vista:

```
  @model WebAPI.Models.Datos

@{
    ViewBag.Title = "Home Page";
}

<form method="get" action=".">
    type simulate
    <input type="text" name="ip" value="@Model.IP" />
    <button>submit</button>
</form>

<!--mce:0-->
<table>
    <tr>
        <td>IP</td>
        <td>@Model.IP</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country code</td>
        <td>@Model.CountryCode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Country name</td>
        <td>@Model.CountryName</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Region code</td>
        <td>@Model.RegionCode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Region name</td>
        <td>@Model.RegionName</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>City</td>
        <td>@Model.City</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Zip code</td>
        <td>@Model.ZipCode</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Time zone</td>
        <td>@Model.TimeZone</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Latitude</td>
        <td>@Model.Latitude</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Longitude</td>
        <td>@Model.Longitude</td>
    </tr>
    <tr>
        <td>Metro code</td>
        <td>@Model.MetroCode</td>
    </tr>
</table>
```

Comment: @Xique de hecho solo cambia `IActionResult` por `ActionResult`, este error me lo sigue marcando `HttpContext`

Comment: @Xique `HttpContext` como seria en Asp.net no le encuentro forma

Comment: es una directiva de core asi que no  creo que puedas usarla es esta ->
using Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc;

Comment: @Xique entonces no hay manera de cambiar el codigo a MVC?

Comment: Si es `.NET Core` solo es necesario realizar la referencia a `Microsoft.AspNetCore.Mvc`. Acabo de probar tu código y no he tenido problema.

Comment: @Davlio si es `.NET Core` pero quiero hacerlo en `ASP.NET MVC`

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Para ASP.NET MVC podrías considerar:

```
public async Task<ActionResult> Index(string ip)
{
    if (string.IsNullOrEmpty(ip))
    {
        ip = Request.UserHostAddress;
    }

    var model = await Datos.QueryGeographicalLocationAsync(ip);

    return View(model);
}
```

El código `Request.HttpContext.Connection.RemoteIpAddress.MapToIPv4().ToString();` solo es contemplado para `.NET Core`, por opté por un símil para `ASP.NET MVC`.